# How to avoi nginx to redirect a POST to a GET

Tags: nginx

I am see this in my log

> "POST /openDoor HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"
>
> "GET /openDoor/ HTTP/1.1" 200 113 "https:///openDoor" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"

I am doing a POST to /openDoor and I get a 301. why?

My nginx conf file is this

```
server {

    client_body_buffer_size 30M;
    client_max_body_size 30M;


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

        proxy_buffer_size          1024k;
        proxy_buffers              32 2048k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    2048k;
    }


    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args =404;
    }


    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log  warn;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

    server_name <redacted>;

    root /var/www/project;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<redacted>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<redacted>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

How to avoid this strange redirect?

I tried this, without any results

```
location /openDoor {
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  expires -1;
  add_header Cache-Control no-store;
  try_files /openDoor/index.php =404;
}


location /openDoor/ {
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  expires -1;
  add_header Cache-Control no-store;
  try_files /openDoor/index.php =404;
}
```

Comment: Replace `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args =404;` with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;`

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: What is that `/openDoor` prefix? Is it a route that should be processed by the `root /var/www/project/index.php` central controller or is it a directory where some additional webapp is located?

Comment: /openDoor is a physical directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `openDoor` is a physical directory, it is nginx that does that 301 `/openDoor` to `/openDoor/` redirect and with the HTTP 301 redirection user browser will change the request method from `POST` to `GET` abandoning the request body. You can try to specify the [HTTP 308 redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308) explicitly with the

```
location = /openDoor {
    return 308 $request_uri;
}
```

Although is isn't directly related to your question, you should replace the

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args =404;
```

line with the

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

The reason is that `try_files` directive processed the files with the `location` block context, and since you don't have a FastCGI handler in that location your `index.php` file will be served as a plain text. On the other hand the very last `try_files` parameter will be treated as a new URI and the right `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` will be chosen to serve it.

Comment: I cannot use a redirect because I  call it using a POST (the customer, not my fault.. long sad story as usually), and in this way I got a POST redirected as GET

Comment: You mean you got the `POST` method change to the `GET` one even using the `HTTP 308` redirection?

Comment: Yes, Ivan, exactly.